# Wordpress can't write to DB after migration

Tags: mysql, wordpress

We moved the WooCommerce webstore to a new server, and there are problems with the communication of the database and Wordpress, it seems the DB got corrupted somehow.
When I import the DB to the new server's empty DB, it gives the error

## 1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

The front end seems fine, but many areas don't function (I believe where the writing to db occurs) - eg. comments, file upload and Order - which gives 502 Error.

I checked error_log and it gives some errors like this

[21-Jan-2016 16:28:27 UTC] WordPress adatbázis hiba Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' a lekérdezésben INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `post_type`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_parent`, `menu_order`, `post_mime_type`, `guid`) VALUES (1, '2016-01-21 17:28:27', '2016-01-21 16:28:27', '', '', 'Order – január 21, 2016 @ 05:28 DU.', 'Próba', 'wc-pending', 'shop_order', 'open', 'closed', 'order_56a1072beeea3', 'rendeles-jan-21-2016-0428-pm', '', '', '2016-01-21 17:28:27', '2016-01-21 16:28:27', 0, 0, '', '') készítette require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout, WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->create_order, wc_create_order, wp_insert_post

So I believe it could not write to the appropriate field in the DB, and failed.

Any idea, how I can solve this?

Comment: It looks like maybe your tables and data came through but the auto_increment wasn't set on your primary keys? Check your schema on the table in question and see if the primary key is configured with an AUTO INCREMENT value.

Comment: Thanks, how can I do that through phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I went ahead and posted a full answer - hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may very well be that certain properties of the table fields (like the `AUTO_INCREMENT`) did not get copied over when the schema was copied.

If you are using phpMyAdmin, you can find the table in your database and then click on the Structure tab. For `wp_posts`, you'd probably see something like this:

[image]

In this case, ID is the identity column, and this table has `AUTO_INCREMENT` set. If that is missing from your table, click the `Change` button and you will see options to set it.

Unfortunately, if you have one table missing `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you probably have others - and if one part of the schema is missing, other important things (unique keys, indexes, etc.) might also be left out - so you should probably reevaluate your database import scripts to see if you can export the full db schema.

Comment: Thanks Kristen. So I need to make all the first rows to AUTO? When I tried to make it at meta_id, like that it is set-up at the old domain, I got this error: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key. 
If all fails, we can maybe try to get back to an older backup, but since it is a functioning webshop, it won't be a too wise idea.

Comment: Thanks, at the end I took MySQL Dumper, and reimported the DB from the old one, and it works now! Cheers!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner, but glad it worked! It may have been that your first export didn't provide the full schema.